# How to easy pass a single tuple to the startswith function from the list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to realize search and replace strings functionality in Python. I wrote the following code, but my main problem is to convert list into the tuple. I realized it in two loops, but **Can you help me in an easier way to pass a tuple to the `startswith` function?** (list is in the `rcsv_list` variable)

```
rman_config = ('''
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name TEST are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
''')

rcsv_list = [('RETENTION POLICY', 'TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 5 DAYS'), 
             ('CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP', 'ON'), 
             ('DEVICE TYPE', 'DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET')]

# unpack list of tuples to a single list
rcsv_tmp_list = []
for l in rcsv_list:
    for t in l:
        rcsv_tmp_list.append(t)

# convert list to tuple
rcsv_tuple = tuple(rcsv_tmp_list)

i = 0

for line in rman_config.splitlines():
    if line.startswith(rcsv_tuple, 10):
        line = 'CONFIGURE ' + rcsv_tuple[i] + ' ' + rcsv_tuple[i+1] + ';'
        i += 2
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name TEST are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 5 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET;
```

The main idea of the above code is to pass to the `startswith` function a tuple to search in line in the `rman_config` string. For this purpose, I created `rcsv_tuple` variable with tuple type. This code works fine, but at the end I have two additional questions:

1. **It is possible to simplify above code without unpack and covert variables?** In other words - how to pass a tuple directly to the `startswith` function from a list of tuples?
2. **Is there any other method to search and replace strings in this case?**

PS. I always get `rcsv_list` variable as list of tuple because -> [Cursor.fetchall()](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.fetchall)

Comment: Use `any` as in `if any(e.startswith(tgt) for e in tup)` also, to make a list out of a tuple, just do `list(tup)`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the loop and the construction of the tuple with:

```
rcsv_tuple = sum(rcsv_list, ())
```

Also you can most probably directly iterate the result of your query instead of querying, split, etc:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
   # ...
```

Finally you might eliminate the else clause as you are printing independently of the condition.

Comment: Great!! I love clever solutions like this. :) Thank you.